# Is there a specific name for a directed graph that is composed of only loops?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Recently I have been doing practice questions for my Final exam tomorrow and this one question appeared that was interesting, but I couldn't seem to find the other half of the answer to it.

**Q:
Given the relation $\{(2,2), (3,3)\}$, draw it's associated directed graph and classify the relation.**

**A:
Draw two vertices that have a loop(this is the first half where I draw it of course)**.

Classification of relation: ?

Does anyone know what this relation would be classified as? I know what the vertices are called, which are referred to as isolated vertex, but what would be relation be classified as?

Comment: Yes, the formal name of such relations is *partial identities, coreflexives, sub-identities, (co)vectors, left/right conditions* ... many names, same idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what is meant by "classifying" the relation, I would just answer that the relation is the equality relation over the domain $\{2, 3\}$.

You can throw in the terms reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, as well.  But I think "equality" over a domain is pretty precise.

Comment: Can these be classified as disconnected relations?

Comment: There's only one relation here.  The _graph_ is disconnected for sure, and has just as many connected components as it has nodes (all nodes are isolated), but I have never heard the word "disconnected" apply to relations or even to graphs of this nature.  A graph is disconnected if it simply has two connected components, but I don't think relations themselves are connected.

Comment: I guess, there isn't really a single specific name for the relation, but rather a series of names. This would also include antisymmetric relation.